# Android "tools" namespace in layout xml documentation

Tags: android-layout, namespaces, textview, preview

Per the question here,

[What's "tools:context" in Android layout files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/android-whats-toolscontext-in-layout-files/11110969#11110969)

The 'tools' namespace reference (xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools") has begun to appear in my layouts recently, and I want to know more.  The original post only described the 'tools:context' attribute, but I have also noticed usage of the "tools:listitem" attribute appearing when I have designated a preview layout item for a listview, i.e.

```xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvCustomer"
    tools:listitem="@layout/customer_list_item" >
</ListView>
```

Are there more elements?

What brought me to this 'tools' namespace is that I want to be able to have 'preview-only' text (i.e. in a TextView or EditText) when using the layout designer in eclipse.

Currently, I assign the 'text' or 'hint' property for previewing text when arranging my layouts... but then I always have to remember to clear the preview value from within the code.

Ideally, instead of

```xml
<string name="preview_customer_name">Billy Bob's Roadhouse Pub</string>

...

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCustomerName"
    android:text="@string/preview_customer_name"
</TextView>
```

have a something like:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCustomerName"
    tools:previewText="@string/preview_customer_name"
</TextView>
```

Thanks-

Comment: Could this be accomplished using the @string resources under a custom locale?

Comment: @bjdodson - this solved my problem and works great for my `@string/preview_text` feature.  I just created a new strings resource and picked an unusual language variant and put all my `@string/preview_text_blah` elements in there.  then I can easily toggle to that local in preview mode.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We've just added support for designtime attributes like this in Android Studio 0.2.11. See http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes for more.

Comment: is there any plan for this to find its way into Eclipse/ADT?

Comment: Is there something similar for Spinners?

Comment: It should -- does it not work? (There's code in there to support it but we haven't touched it in a long time so perhaps it accidentally got broken by something else.)

Answer (score 15):

Think of them as design time helpers only.They do not get processed in actual view rendering at run time.

For example you want to set background of some view in your layout design when working on android studio so that you can make clear distinction where that particular view is.So you would normally do that with

```
android:background="@color/<some-color>"
```

Now risk is that sometimes we forget to remove that color and it gets shipped in apk.
instead you can do as follows:

```
tools:background="@color/<some-color>"
```

These changes will be local to android studio and will never get transferred to apk.

And also check out http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes for more options.

Answer (score 8):

You will find `tool` attribute when you set object in graphical layout.

Listview (in graphical mode) -> right Click -> Preview List Content -> Choose Layout...

produces:

```
tools:listitem="@layout/customer_list_item"
```

Answer (score 2):

See in layout XML below. There are 2 namespace in use "**xmlns:android**" and "**xmlns:tools**".

**Tools** namespace is used when the developer wants to define placeholder content that is only used in preview or in design time. Tools namespace is removed when we compiled the app.

So in the code below, I want to show the placeholder image (**image_empty**) that will only be visible at design time, and **image1** will the actual image that will be shown when the application launch

[image]