# Having problems with RelativeLayout (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm pretty new to android studio and app designing and I'm facing some problems in designing an app.

I'm using relative Layout to set the position of different elements on a page but it is not working. I'm including my syntax and results below for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quiz app"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        tools:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        tools:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        tools:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        tools:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password: "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        tools:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        tools:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        tools:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fillblank1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        tools:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
        tools:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        tools:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result is coming as:

[image: when I'm running the app]

Device: on Nexus 6P API 27 Oreo

I did check out the other questions related to relative layout problems but I don't think they are as bad as this case so I asked this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `tools` with `android`.

The 'tools' namespace is only used at design time and not at runtime. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641340/android-tools-namespace-in-layout-xml-documentation)

For example, instead of

```
tools:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

do

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```