# 9-patch drawable behaving badly, weird artefacts - what is wrong here?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

so Im trying out the 9-patch images. I started out with a PNG-file where I have a semi-transparent square with rounded corners:

[image]

Then, I created the 9-patch, like this (note the little dot on top and to the left):

[image]

I thought that was enough to handle this, but when adding this 9-patch to Eclipse, I get weird results.

**Result nbr 1**

Based on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/taxibg3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_square" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I get this result:

[image]

Result nbr 2

Based on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/taxibg3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_square" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get this result:

[image]

I have also tried to make the "9-patch-lines" on the top and left longer, but that also gives weird artefacts.

**Any ideas?**

**-- EDIT --**

I also tried with this 9-patch (screen-shot from 9patch-tool):

[image]

which gives this bad result (note the black lines):

[image]

**---- EDIT 2 ----**

Leonidos told me that the 9-patch was too big, and that they cannot decrease in size. So I tried that out, with equally bad results.

This is the 9-patch (download the file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3wIZ9CS9Kj_M0xwY3FrS1FDLW8/edit))

[image]

and this is how it looks (notice the black lines):

[image]

--- EDIT 3 ---

I took a look at "show bad patches" in the pathtoo, and this is what is shows:

[image]

But it doesnt really matter. If I change it so it looks like this:

[image]

I still get the black stripes!

Oh why oh why!? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it small as possible. 9-patch cant shrink they can stretch. Fill right and bottom border with black color. Edit 9-patch borders with draw9patch tool to prevent errors. Your 9-patch should look similar to [this one](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_TmS45BcrloQ/TDQbGX1mpOI/AAAAAAAAA5U/w0BAjGUbR-4/s320/9patch.png).

Comment: HMm, I will play around with a smaller version now, see how that works out.

Comment: works ) I put your 9patch in drawable folder. Applied it to a view: android:background="@drawable/login_square_adapted" and evething is ok. 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13106986/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-11%20at%202.05.57%20PM.png

Comment: So, a smaller 9-patch works, but the irritating thing is that Eclipse shows the black lines, deploying to device does not (at least; not yet)

Comment: Try do update SDK and Eclipse plugin to the latest version. I develop on Mac and have never saw such artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do 9-patch markings from all 4 sides. Also make sure you have .9.png file extension (f.i. your_cool_pic.9.png)

Here is my example
[image]

Comment: seems correct and moreover OP saying semi-transparent then must sure that not to use any special filter i.e *multiply, highlight, soft, darken etc.. of Photoshop.*

Comment: The effect is made with "bevel/emboss"-filter in Photoshop, but not "multiply" etc etc. But how can that make a difference?

Comment: I now see that the "bevel/emboss"-filter in PS uses "Shadow mode"=Multiply. IS that the culprit? And if so, why? Also, I initially tried with the lines on the bottom and right, but that was of no help.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 pixel border *must* be either completely black (nine patch markers) or completely transparent. Basically, edit the image to cut out anything in the 1 pixel border except for the two black dots.

Also, your image can be much, much smaller in size. The point of a nine patch is that the markers on the top and left sides mark what is to be stretched. Most of that content with straight edges could be removed.

Comment: It is completely black or transparent. I created it using the tool. I know it can be smaller, but this is how I got it from my designer and what I worked with now.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual nine-patch image? Saving the one from the post isn't giving a nine-patch.

Comment: Here is one version with "longer lines" on the side (not the dot): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3wIZ9CS9Kj_bjlJVEZnRlkxbTg/edit

Comment: Here are two more versions of the same:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3wIZ9CS9Kj_VDZ3VVRyWWcyelk/edit
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3wIZ9CS9Kj_aWFDR1NjUF9ibEU/edit

Comment: Looks like the problem is because the nine-patch is bigger than the View you're using it in (as stated by @Leonidos). You need to make it smaller - ideally as small as possible.

Comment: Hmm, doesnt seem to work with a smaller one either, please see my Edit 2 above.