# Android - adding custom border to image view

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to have an image view in my app that has a border something like the follows :

[image]

I only have the image for the border, and the imageview, and somehow need to fit the imageview inside the border (the border image is transparent - like the one used in this question is downloaded from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=EfTws2kGBmePJM&tbnid=aOD6_rN1rtqOsM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconarchive.com%2Fshow%2Ficons8-metro-style-icons-by-visualpharm%2FVery-Basic-Frame-icon.html&ei=1q2uU5btM4qRyASRoIGQCQ&bvm=bv.69837884,d.aWw&psig=AFQjCNE5fCvO7XZHJHWVq_gVfhPGTFGCxg&ust=1404042928613021)).

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: you can use one image that center of that is transparent, then fit another imageView on it

Answer (score 1):

There is many solutions that you can do.

- Extend an ImageView Class and Override OnDraw(Canvas) and Draw your Image on the Canvas of the ImageView by using paint and shader and provide the size of the rect to draw over then Draw the Frame.
- Set Background of ImageView as Frame and Ur Image as Src giving the a padding that will make the Src Image fit inside the Transparent Area.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, save it as "frame.9.png" as 9patch, drop it to drawables folder:

[image]

Exampe pic in frame, it should be bigger, example:

[image]

Example as layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/cat"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Remember,  9-patch cant shrink they can stretch. Info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274623/619673

Cat image was downloaded from http://www.socwall.com/wallpapers/search:cat/