# What is the meaning of xmlns:tools in Android XML layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tools-namespace

For example, in:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
...
```

Do I need to put it?

Comment: There's some good information along these lines in [What's “tools:context” in Android layout files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11078487/1267661)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It defines the XML namespace of the document. You should put it, otherwise tags like `<RelativeLayout>` could be not recognied by the parser.

Namespaces are a way for XML documents to include tags from various vendors. By using `xmlns` attribute you declare, that, by default, you're using XML elements defined here: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android (note that this link is broken - [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2FtsLQ4wESY) explains why).

You also declare additional namespace, `tools`, which is not your default namespace, thus when referencing elements or attributes defined there, you must add `tools` prefix, on example:

```
tools:context=".SomeActivity"
```

Comment: @Sam - That's because Google does not make it public.

Comment: @Sam - see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2FtsLQ4wESY) to see why those schemas are not available.

Comment: Did you do a ninja edit? I swear that was a different link attached to a different sentence... maybe I just zoned out. I agree, schemas are not required to be valid links, just consistent.

Comment: @Sam - I did, to update answer with link to the discussion (i also fixed a link) - but the exact link doesn't matter, because all xmlns's from Android aren't defined.

Comment: Just update, you can find tool attributes explanations here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: This actually doesn't answer about `tools`. This answer is for `xmlns:android`

Comment: @kamituel The link to the discussion does not work anymore either.

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) - Updated link

Answer (score 5):

Following is a useful link from Android dev portal: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html

It says

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

i.e. tools namespace helps designing UI and all attributes with prefix 'tools' will be removed at build time.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when you do :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id> </RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of calling android:id, the xml will call http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:id . It just the page that declare all the attribute and views that you can use in your xml.

Here is an explanation.
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the `xmlns:tools` attribute is used to define the XML namespace for the "tools" namespace prefix. It is commonly used in layout XML files to provide additional tools and information to aid in the development process. The `tools` namespace provides attributes that are used during the design and development of the app, but are ignored or stripped out during compilation and execution.

Here's an example of how the `xmlns:tools` attribute is typically used in an Android layout XML file:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above example, the `tools:context` attribute is used to specify the activity class associated with the layout for design-time rendering and preview purposes. The `tools:text` attribute is used to provide placeholder text that is only displayed in the Android Studio layout editor, but not at runtime.

By utilizing the `tools` namespace, developers can customize the appearance and behavior of their layouts specifically for design and testing purposes without affecting the final production code.