# Android Material Design: Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-theme, material-design

I am trying to use the toolbar widget in android 21 with a custom style but I can't get rid off this error : 
`Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme`.

Here is my layout xml file :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/patient_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Patient" />
```

Here is the Patient theme :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Patient" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/patient_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/patient_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/patient_accent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle"></item> <!-- what values to put here -->
</style>
```

I also tried to add `toolbarStyle` in item in my theme but I don't know the possible values. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the style Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.

```
<!-- Toolbar styles -->
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
```

Comment: Additionally,

You can use the @android:style for any style that you're basing your theme from

    <!-- Toolbar styles -->
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem event though my xml was correct.
The solution was to: **Set AppCompat theme in the Theme Select Checkbox**, see pic.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you have to install Android Support libs in SDK Manager

Comment: @Riten, you can choose "Project Themes"

Comment: The above mentioned problem also raised for me. And you solution worked . Thank you @DavidA

Comment: If you're like me, you may have been missing the `tools:context` tag in your root node which helps the preview pick up the right theme. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files