# Am trying to make a splash screen with a fade-in animated TextView

Tags: java, android, mobile, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen with a fixed photo and animated text. However, the application always stops when launching. In the logcat, the only problem that appears is in SplashScreen line 17, and more specifically this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
```

My code:

activity_splash_screen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lenovo.tryfinal.SplashScreen">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/garagny"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Park Easily"
    android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
    android:textSize="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/ParkEasily"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
package com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

TextView ParkEasily;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    ParkEasily = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParkEasily);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashScreen.this, R.anim.fade_in);
    ParkEasily.startAnimation(fade1);

    ParkEasily.startAnimation(fade1);

    fade1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startActivity(new
                    Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){
        }



    });
}
}
```

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa I think the app is crashing at launch and would be caused by SplashScreen on line 17

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication/com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: at com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:17)

Answer (score 2):

Your xml context refers this:

tools:context="com.example.lenovo.tryfinal.SplashScreen"

but your package is:

com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication;

Your xml contex should be (tools:context="com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication.SplashScreen")

Comment: Layout cant be inflated. Because contex is different.

Comment: As per my knowledge "tools:context" is used by Android Studio to render the activity screen in Preview. It will not be used at run time when application is built. You may refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files for more details

Comment: You right, I know it is used by android studio to render the activity screen in Preview. But, I get the same crash, when ı changed the context, crash disappeared. I don't know why it happens. Maybe, it can be android studio bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import the R of your app. Try add "import {your package name}.R" line above Activity class. If it still shows error message, clean your project and check your xml file whether it has error. Then, build again and try to import generated R file.

Answer (score 0):

Your SplashActivity  class is under package **com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication**

But your tools:context in xml is **com.example.lenovo.tryfinal.SplashScreen**

Make them same. in xml make it

```
   tools:context="com.example.lenovo.garagnyapplication.SplashScreen"
```