# Cannot resolve symbol "Hello World" error,right after I started a new project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

**What's my Problem :** I started app development using android studio today and I can't seem to get past the first part. The content after `android:text="` in **content_main.xml** is always in red and it is being referred to as an error, even when I'm not referring to the **strings.xml**.

**What all did I try :** I read up on previous answers and I read that there must be something wrong with my xml file, that I might have messed up something which should have been there. I tried *clean/rebuild*. Then I deleted this project and started a new one but the problem didn't go.

SURPRISINGLY THOUGH, removing `tools.context=".MainActivity"` solved it.

**What I want to know :** Is it ok for me to continue working without the tool.context . I mean I have no idea what it does and what exactly is causing the problem. I would love to know a proper fix.

Here I am attaching the image for my xml file.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFS8z.png)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting on the content after `android:text="`?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'string'. Here string refers to android:text="**string**"

Comment: Did you try **Build -> Clean Project** ?

Comment: In the image you attached you're commenting tools:context *and* the > that closes the tag, so technically the rest of the file is wrong (see the red underline before the beginning of the TextView tag and the red underline in </RelativeLayout.

Comment: ok, right. It didn't fix anything. It simply didn't compile to show me the error. And i tried clean project and then rebuild project, didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine for you to continue developing without the `tools:context` attribute, this is only used at design time and it will ignore when you build your APK as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files).

---

You haven't really solved the issue on the second image btw, you have a bad formed XML and your project won't compile.

Comment: Try invalidating Android Studio cache. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/2503185

Comment: Setting up the JDK home? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found

Comment: Ok, i tried clean once again, then did sync build with gradle. Restarted the whole thing. It still shows the string in red(and says cannot resolve symbol 'string') but is compiling the way I want it to.

Comment: the avd shows the right output. This helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio