# What is the real purpose of tools:context in Android XML

Tags: android, xml

I'm learning android and wonder why I can't find the real purpose of the attribute `tools:context` in layout XML file.

I read here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolscontext under the image that `onClick` will not work for any View until we specify `tools:context`.

I tried and wonder it is working without any `tools:context`
I also read from the stackoverflow that it used to choose proper theme for the layout. But it is working fine for me without using `tools:context` then what is the real purpose of this?

**XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="CallIt"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.something.testingwith42;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void CallIt(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Checking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine without `tools:context`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> onClick will not work for any View until we specify tools:context

There is nothing in that documentation that makes that claim.

> Everything is working fine without tools:context

Correct. That is because that is nothing in that documentation that states that `onClick()` will only work if you have `tools:context`. It *does* say that for quick-fixes, you need `tools:context` for the tools to know where to add the `onClick()` method.

> also read from the stackoverflow that it used to choose proper theme for the layout

This too is incorrect.

> What is the real purpose of tools:context in Android XML

It provides context for development tools, as to where this layout will be used, so that the tools can provide better assistance to developers, such as:

- more accurate rendering of previews, taking the hosting activity and its theme into account
- more intelligent assistants, such as the aforementioned quick-fixes

`tools:context` is completely optional. Development tools can and do work without it. Those tools may provide somewhat degraded assistance to you, but that is your choice.

`tools:context` — or any attribute in the `tools` namespace — will have no impact at runtime. I have not checked, but I would hope that they even get stripped out when packaging the APK, as they have no use at runtime.

Comment: So if I specify method on `onClick` then will it search for that method in all packages to call?

Comment: @Nothing: No, it searches for it in whatever activity loaded the layout (directly or indirectly). If you need greater flexibility than that, use [the data binding framework](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).