# Navigation Preview unavailable in Android Studio 3.2 Preview

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-studio-3.2

I am interested to try the Navigation graph showed in the Android Studio. But I got the preview unavailable after I import the [google sample](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/ComponentsBasicSample.zip)

I used the Android Studio 3.2 Preview Canary 16

[image]

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@+id/launcher_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/launcher_home"
        android:name="com.android.samples.arch.componentsbasicsample.StartFragment"
        android:label="Home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/end_action"
            app:destination="@id/end_dest" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/end_dest"
        android:name="com.android.samples.arch.componentsbasicsample.EndFragment"
        android:label="End"
        >

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**Update on 10/6/2018:**

Even I rebuild the project it doesn't work. But if added new screen, it showed the new one in preview mode

[image]

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You should click on "text" tab in navigation editor (xml file of the navigation graph), and add:

```
tools:layout="@layout/layout_name"
```

inside destination element.

Should be something like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/someFragment"
    android:name="com.freesoulapps.navigationtest.fragments.SomeFragment"
    android:label="Some Fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/layout_name">
</fragment>
```

Comment: Okay. This solution works. But I have one question about this statement. How can I use the default fragment layout instead of the design time layout?

Comment: The navigation editor doesn't know about the layout that you put inside "onCreateView" method of your fragment.

Comment: it is not correct, even you create the blank Activity with the Fragment one, the design panel still show the fragment layout in activity.xml without setting the design time attribute.

Comment: I didn't understood, where you create blank activity? inside navigation editor?

Answer (score 20):

there is another way to have the preview in navigation xml.
First go in your xml fragment add

```
tools:context="com.packagename.nameFragment"
```

[image: exemple for my frag layout]

And that's it

if you go in your navigation file you can see the preview inside the selection and the navigation editor

[image]
[image]

And if you look in the code is auto write

```
tools:layout="@layout/layout_name"
```

For me is more logic to have the preview before add the fragment in the navigation editor.
May be there are method for add automatically the tools:context in the layout

Autocompletation not suggest for tools:context Fragment only suggest the tools:context Activity host so you need to write the fragment's name... if someone have a trick for this

learn more about tools:context :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files)

Comment: Is it working for you in case of usage fragment with ViewModel, so first in xml you have <layout..... and after deflation of main e.g. ConstraintLayout ? I have tested it recently and no preview is available.

Answer (score 15):

Just add
tools:layout="fragmentname"
to every fragment whose preview is not visible.
Example:-

```
<navigation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pickupFragment"
        android:name="com.example.cup_cake.PickupFragment"
        android:label="fragment_pickup"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pickup" />

</navigation>
```