# Default activity not found issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

i am making an application. first this was working fine. then after certain changes i have restarted android studio. But Now i am getting error That default activity is not found.
here is my manifest code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i don't know where i am doing mistake [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gzDJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Look the action section, at the end of the line you have "-->". Remove it and i think it will works.

This line : `"<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->"`
remove the "-->" at the end.

Comment: Can you please put the green tick on my answer to  informa that you had an answer plz

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem . Remove the encircled extra characters

> -->

[image: problematic code]

Comment: bro i have removed it/

Comment: is it fixed, or do you still have the problem ?

Comment: yes. also my xml file is showing error that activity not found?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of that may be ? and make sure that the SplashActivity exists in the "activities" package

Comment: yes this is is activities packages. this was working fine. now it is not working. i have added the snapshot please check it

Comment: Try cleaning the project. If it doesn't work, then simply remove this line. Its not that important. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files )