# CardView onClick java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add a click listener for each cardview in a grid layout, but I get the following error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.uspherejda/com.example.uspherejda.HomeScreen}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //SQL
    private SatFromHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private CardView satList, addSat, satType, satCountries, aboutMe, goCrazy;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        dbHelper = new SatFromHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //call the Home fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        //Set up a custom bar using a custom
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.start_dark_blue)));
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_bar_image, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(view);
        //Card views.
        satList = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdList);
        addSat = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdForm);
        satType = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdSatTypes);
        satCountries = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdCountries);
        aboutMe = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdAboutMe);
        goCrazy = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.crdGoCrayCraaaaay);

         satList.setOnClickListener(this);
         addSat.setOnClickListener(this);
         satType.setOnClickListener(this);
         satCountries.setOnClickListener(this);
         aboutMe.setOnClickListener(this);
         goCrazy.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Bottom Navigation
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        //Item listener when one of hte items below from the nav_bar is selected
        bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_list:
                    selectedFragment = new ListFragment(dbHelper, db);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_add:
                    selectedFragment = new AddFragment(dbHelper, db);
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.crdList: startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListFragment.class));
            break;
        }

    }
    //Close the db when the activity onDestroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dbHelper.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My Dashboard"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
                <GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:rowCount="4"
                    android:columnCount="2"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:columnOrderPreserved="false">
                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/crdList"
                                android:layout_width="170dp"
                                android:layout_height="170dp"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:gravity="center">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="84dp"
                                    android:layout_height="84dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/satdashboard"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Satellite List"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/crdForm"
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp">
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:gravity="center">
                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                            android:layout_width="84dp"
                                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/formdashboard"/>

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Add a Satellite"
                                            android:textSize="16sp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/crdSatTypes"
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:gravity="center">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="84dp"
                                    android:layout_height="84dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/sattypes"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Types of Satellites"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/crdCountries"
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="84dp"
                                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/countrysats" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                            android:text="Satellite Countries"
                                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/crdAboutMe"
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="84dp"
                                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/aboutme" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                            android:text="About Me"
                                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/crdGoCrayCraaaaay"
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/center_light_blue"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="84dp"
                                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/gocrazy" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                            android:text="Go Crazy!"
                                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you use `setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);` and then you use `beginTransaction` to swap out fragments. findViewById will try to find the view on on the activity, not on the fragment.

Comment: should i just begin the transaction after the cardviews listeners? or should i just declare these cardviews inside the HomeFragment instead?

Comment: `should i just begin the transaction after the cardviews listeners?` that would make no difference, the view you're trying to find _wont be found_  because you're not looking for it in the right place. if it's on the fragment, trying to find it on the activity won't work, regardless of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just declared the cardviews in my HomeFragment.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        //Card views.
        satList = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdList);
        addSat = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdForm);
        satType = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdSatTypes);
        satCountries = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdCountries);
        aboutMe = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdAboutMe);
        goCrazy = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.crdGoCrayCraaaaay);
        //listeners
        satList.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
        //addSat.setOnClickListener(this);
        //satType.setOnClickListener(this);
        //satCountries.setOnClickListener(this);
        //aboutMe.setOnClickListener(this);
        //goCrazy.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.crdList: getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homeFragment, new ListFragment(dbHelper, db)).commit();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am almost certain what error is in the reference of your xml:

```
tools:context=".HomeFragment"
```

Should to be:

```
tools:context=".HomeScreen"
```

Are you sure this xml belongs to your activity HomeScreen?

The java code belongs to an activity and its xml belongs to a Fragment.

Comment: actually switching between both does nothing but what i am doing here is calling the home fragment in my activty and controlling the other fragments through my homescreen activity, but i changed the context and i am still getting the same error, probably the fragments are causing this issue

Comment: That's why, you should have a class specific for the fragment 'HomeFragment'. Currently you are calling fragment's elements ID inside of a Activity, and that's why you get NullPointerException. The findViewById should to be in the class HomeFragment.

Comment: the tools namespace makes no difference to a running app, it's just there for debugging and while we develop - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078487/whats-toolscontext-in-android-layout-files